# Auditing using Rebus 2 on Azure Service Bus

Tags: azure, rebus

I have something like this in my code

```
bus =  Configure.With(activator)
                .Options(o => o.SimpleRetryStrategy(errorQueueAddress: configuration.GetStringSettings("ErrorQueue")))
                .Routing(r => r.TypeBased().Map<MyMessage>("endpointQueueName"))
                .Transport(a => a.UseAzureServiceBus(configuration.GetStringSettings("AzureConnectionString"), configuration.GetStringSettings("InputQueueAddress"), Rebus.AzureServiceBus.Config.AzureServiceBusMode.Standard))
                .Options(o => o.EnableMessageAuditing("auditQueueName"))
                .Start();
...

bus.Send(message);
```

Assuming that "endpointQueueName" and "auditQueueName" exist on my azure service bus namespace. When i send a message of type MyMessage, i expect to find it in "endpointQueueName" queue and in "auditQueueName" queue but this doesn't happening. I find it only in "endpointQueueName" queue.

Why?

What I'm doing wrong in configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are observing the correct behavior :)

As stated in [the Message Auditing documentation](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/wiki/Message-auditing) messages get copied to the audit queue *before the message disappears*, i.e. either

- when HANDLING a message
- when PUBLISHING a message (because it could be published to 0 subscribers - Rebus has no way of knowing)

So if your handler (which must also have message auditing configured) properly handles the message, you should see a copy (with some extra headers) in the audit queue.

I hope that makes it clearer :)